# Setting nested enum value as default parameter in class __init__

Tags: python, nested

I have a nested enum which holds two possible value for a parameter of a class. I would like to give on enum as the default value for the class in the `__init__`

Something that would look like that:

```
from enum import IntEnum as IntEnum
class A:
    class AParam(IntEnum):
        TYPE_1 = 1
        TYPE_2 = 2
    def __init__(self, param=A.AParam.TYPE_1):
        self.param = param
```

Of course It dosen't work, I guess because the class is not fully constructed yet.

The alternative solution I'm doing right now is this:

```
from enum import IntEnum as IntEnum
class A:
    class AParam(IntEnum):
        TYPE_1 = 1
        TYPE_2 = 2

    def __init__(self, param=None):
        if param is None:
            param = A.AParam.TYPE_1
        self.param = param
```

For several reasons, I don't want to use strings instead of enums. I could use also not put the parameter in the `init`, and just let the class user use the member variable itself. But then the default parameter is not so explicit.

Is there another way of passing nested enum as default value for the `__init__` method ? Or is that just not possible...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can regard the inside of the class as a scope, not unlike the scope inside a function.

Therefore, you can do this:

```
class A:

    class AParam(IntEnum):
        TYPE_1 = 1
        TYPE_2 = 2

    def __init__(self, param=AParam.TYPE_1):
        self.param = param
```

Note the missing `A.`.

This scope is active during the definition of the contents of the class.

Comment: It can be a bit surprising at first. It also explains how a `def` or nested classes inside a class work exactly the same way as other `def` and `class` statements.